# I need help to debug my XML parsing please

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa-touch, parsing

I'm parsing this line:

`<type>branch</type>`

with this code in `didEndElement`

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"type"]) {

        [currentBranchDictionary setValue:currentText forKey:currentElementName];

    }
```

When I test the value in the `type` key, it does not contain `branch` but instead it contains `branch\n`.  Here is the test I'm performing:

```
    if ([[currentBranchDictionary valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"branch"]) {
        NSLog(@"no new-line");
    } else if ([[currentBranchDictionary valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"branch\n"]) {
        NSLog(@"new-line");
    }
```

this returns the "new-line" output

Here's the foundCharacters method:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    [currentText appendString:string];
}
```

I don't understand where the carriage return is being added, can anyone help?

Comment: What method is the first code snippet in?  Show the foundCharacters method.  What other places is currentText being set or modified?

Comment: The first code snippet is in didEndElement.  I'll post the found characters method, thanks.

Comment: I also do `currentText = [NSMutableString string];` in `didStartElement`

Comment: Don't see anything obvious.  Is there only one <type> element returned in the xml?  Is currentBranchDictionary modified after the xml parsing?  In didEndElement, why is currentElementName used for the key instead of elementName (check that it's set correctly).  In the xml, do any other tags have the value branch\n?

Comment: There are numerous `<type>` elements, none of them have `\n` in the source file.  `CurrentBranchDictionary` is used to hold the contents of several elements.  Every one of them is being appended with `\n`.

Comment: I've established something, the `\n` is not in currentText but is being returned from the dictionary, is this normal?

Comment: Not normal.  Is currentBranchDictionary a subclass of NSDictionary or an instance of it?  Put the test for \n right after doing the setValue.  Some other code might be adding the \n later.

Comment: Here's the definition of the dictionary `NSMutableDictionary *currentBranchDictionary;`  I'll test for \n in a few places and see what comes back, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your XML contains carriage returns ("\r") that aren't being displayed by your editor.  The XML specification requires these to be translated to line feeds ("\n") prior to reporting the result to your application:

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends

Can you verify the contents of your XML file?  What is the output from the xxd command?  Here's the output from a file I created.  Note the extra 0d character:

```
0000000: 3c74 7970 653e 6272 616e 6368 0d3c 2f74  <type>branch.</t
0000010: 7970 653e                                ype>
```

Comment: Hi bkail, I hand-typed the lines containing `<type>branch</type>` and they do not have carriage returns.  If I output `currentText` before I place its contents into the dictionary, it has no carriage return.  If I output the `valueForKey:@"type"` immediately after setting it, it has no carriage return.  However, if I output `valueForKey:@"type"` after I leave `didEndElement` it does have a carriage return.  I don't understand why.

Comment: I discovered the problem.  The `\r` was after the closed element, for example `<type>branch</type>\r`.  This meant that I was closing the element, calling `didEndElement` where I would output `currentText` and this would contain `branch`.  However, then `foundCharacters` would be called for the `\r` at the end of the line.  This would append the `\r` to `currentText` whose value was pointed to by `[currentBranchDictionary valueForKey:@"type"]`.  QED